# Need to traverse the SO Lines - and check with Customized Fields

Tags: acumatica

I need Sales Order to be marked open only when some of the Customized fields in the SO Line Table are entered and checked with some other tables.

I created an event - 
HoW do I traverse the SO Lines and their extension fields here ??

```
//    protected void SOOrder_Hold_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
//    {
//      if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
//        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
//      var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
//      string ordtype = row.OrderType;
//      string ordnbr = row.OrderNbr;

//      if (row.Hold == false)/
//      {
//           foreach (SOLine record in
//                    PXSelectReadonly<SOLine,
//                    Where<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderType>>, 
//                    And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>>.Select(Base, ordtype, ordnbr))
//           {
//                             cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SOOrder.hold>(
//                            row, row.Hold,
//                              new PXSetPropertyException("Product Module Sample Project Check", PXErrorLevel.Warning));    
//           }
//        }    
//    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would actually suggest using a FieldVerifying Event

```
protected virtual void SOOrder_Hold_FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e, PXFieldVerifying del)
{
    //Calls other handlers if they exist.
    //Important for Acumatica Events / Other Customizations
    if (del != null)
    {
        del(sender, e);
    }

    SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;

    if (row != null && !((e.NewValue as bool?) ?? false))
    {
        bool allFieldsProper = true;

        SOLine line;
        SOLineExtension lineExt;

        foreach (PXResult<SOLine, INItemCost> res in Base.Transactions.Select())
        {
            line = res[0] as SOLine;
            lineExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExtension>();

            if (lineExt.UsrField != "Some Value")
            {
                allFieldsProper = false;
                //No point in further evaluation if 1 is wrong
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!allFieldsProper)
        {
            throw new PXSetPropertyException<SOOrder.hold>("Error", PXErrorLevel.Error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good recommendation of FieldVerifying based on the users question and the posted code

Answer (score 0):

The SO Lines are stored in the Transactions `DataView` of the `SOOrderEntryGraph`.
To work with them and check any custom fields(from the extension) you can do the following:

```
protected void SOOrder_Hold_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
    //if(InvokeBaseHandler!=null)   - remove comments from these lines if you need to call the base method
    //    InvokeBaseHandler(cache,e);  
    if(e.Row!=null)
    {
        SOOrder currentOrder = (SOOrder) e.Row;
        foreach (IEnumerator<PXResultSet<SOLine>> linesEnumerator in this.Base.Transactions.Select().GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (linesEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                SOLine currentLine = (SOLine)linesEnumerator.Current;
                var currentLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(currentLine);// replace SOLineExt with the name of your DAC's Cache Extension's class name
                //----
                // Here add your checking 
                //----
            }
        }
    }
}
```